# Design of programming with databases for DB tables with many columns

Tags: database, oop

*I'd like to share & ask for your help on the following design issue:*

I have a DB table which contains 11 columns

Whenever I approach these conditions in any programming language,

*I am stuck with the question:*

"how do I create a function to insert a row, without the function having 11 parameters?"
my issue is, that it's a problem of bad design (since it's a lot of parameters in one function)

can anyone tell me how to redesign this?
Do I have to change my DB scheme? 
or can I leave it the way it is, and just build my application differently?

**Note:**

I have found a lot of similar questions, but they all focused on the Database itself & the number of columns.

As far as I know & read, as long as it's the same entity, a table can hold many columns.

I am more concerned with the function itself. 
meaning if I have a *class called DB*, and a function called *insertToTable(Params...)*
how can I do it differenty?

if I send one big object to the DB class, doesn't it affect "*low coupling high cohesion*"?
and isn't it kind of stupid, setting the parameters in the object, then sending it to the DB class, and then getting them back in order to build this huge query?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider creating several insert methods that accept different number of parameters based on the default values, what data is updated and such.

If you frequently update only 2 or 3 columns why not write a function that will only accept these 3 parameters and keep everything else the same.

Yes, you will need to have one function that does accept all parameters but you can deal with that by creating a class that represents a table and then passing just one parameter - object of that class.